# Self join of time series data

Tags: sql, join

I need some help with what I think should be a fairly simple self join query.  It just needs to combine the matching start time and end times from two records into one record

Say I have the following in a table

```
Time  Event
08:00 Start
09:00 Stop
10:30 Start
10:45 Stop
11:00 Start
11:15 Start
12:00 Stop
12:30 Stop
```

I want a view like this

```
StartTime Stoptime
08:00  09:00 
10:30  10:45 
11:00 
11:15  12:00 
       12:30
```

Notice it should find the closest matching start or end time.  If for some reason there is not a matching event it should leave it blank.

Thanks,

Comment: Something's funny in your data and output.  You show events starting at 11:00 and 11:15 and then events stopping at 12:00 and 12:30. Then your sample view shows the Start and Stop time for events as 11:00 and 11:15 and then 12:00 and 12:30 (typo). I'm assuming those last two records should be 11:00, 12:00 and 11:15 and 12:30.

Comment: The 13:30 should be 12:30,  I fixed it but my edit is not showing up for some reason.  The start time and end time that should be matched up should always be the closest ones together time wise.  On rare occasions the system my not record a start or end time for an event so they should be left blank

Comment: Having an row-level order dependency is a violation of 1NF, the best thing you can do with any level of sanity is to match a start time with the next available end time. This would put 11:00 Start / 12:00 Finish, 11:15 Start, 13:30 Finish. You should put a unique task description in the data so your primary key is (Task, Event)

Comment: @Evan, thanks for the comment. I left off any Task field to simplify the problem. You can assume that only one type of task would be in the table or that the final query would filter the events down to only one type of Tasks. I did not mean to imply that the order of the records should matter only time stamps.

Comment: But you did. Could you explain why 11:00 isn't matched up to 12:00?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*disclaimer:*
I would seriously consider a different table design.  Joining on dates and or times is never a good idea.  If you had an ID of the event that is starting, you could easily LEFT JOIN to try to find the matching end of that event.

For SQL Server try:

```
DECLARE @Events  table (EventTime char(5), EventType varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('08:00','Start')
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('09:00','Stop')
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('10:30','Start')
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('10:45','Stop')
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('11:00','Start')
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('11:15','Start')
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('12:00','Stop')
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('12:30','Stop')

SELECT
    dt.StartTime, dt.StopTime
    FROM (SELECT
              p.EventTime AS StartTime,CASE WHEN c.EventType!='Stop' THEN NULL ELSE c.EventTime END AS StopTime
                  ,p.EventTime AS SortBy
              FROM @Events          p
                INNER JOIN @Events  c ON p.EventTime<c.EventTime
              WHERE p.EventType='Start'
                  AND c.EventTime=(SELECT MIN(EventTime) FROM @Events WHERE  EventTime>p.EventTime)
          UNION
          SELECT
              NULL AS StartTime,p.EventTime
                  ,p.EventTime AS SortBy
              FROM @Events          p
                INNER JOIN @Events  c ON p.EventTime>c.EventTime
              WHERE p.EventType='STOP'
                  AND c.EventTime=(SELECT MAX(EventTime) FROM @Events WHERE  EventTime<p.EventTime)
                  AND c.EventType='Stop'
         ) dt
    ORDER BY dt.SortBy
```

OUTPUT:

```
StartTime StopTime
--------- --------
08:00     09:00
10:30     10:45
11:00     NULL
11:15     12:00
NULL      12:30

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  In this case the data is logged by a 3rd party package that I have no control over so they don't have an ID field to link the events.  I am just trying to display the events in a more meaningful format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using the *SQL* tag to mean *sql-server*.  But in case future seekers are interested in an Oracle solution this problem can be solved with the analytic `LEAD()` and `LAG()` functions...

```
SQL> select * from (
  2      select case when event = 'Start' then t else null end as start_t
  3             , case when next_event = 'Stop' then next_t
  4                    when event = 'Stop' and prev_event = 'Stop' then next_t
  5                    else null end as stop_t
  6      from (
  7          select event
  8                  , t
  9                  , lead (t) over (order by t) as next_t
 10                  , lead (event) over (order by t) as next_event
 11                  , lag (event) over (order by t) as prev_event
 12          from t23
 13          order by t )
 14      )
 15  where start_t is not null
 16  or    stop_t is not null
 17  /

START STOP_
----- -----
08:00 09:00
10:30 10:45
11:00
11:15 12:00
      12:30

SQL>
```