# How to move C# data processing to SQL Server for a complex logic

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have a EventLogs table in SQL Server which is consists of columns ComputerId,EventDateTime, EventType and UserId, clients dump logs into the table. Since the logs arrive to SQL at random times, we have a C# logic in place which given the startDate and EndDate, returns logs then run the logic which is to create list of session pairs for each given computer. This process is CPU intensive and lots of data is sent over the wire from SQL to App. Is it possible to convert the following C# logic into SQL query so that the only list of session pairs are return. Creating a list of session pair which consists of LoginTime and LogOut

```
 async Task<IEnumerable<SessionsView>> GetSessionPairs(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, List<string> computersList = null, List<string> usersList = null)
         {
                    var sessionStart = new Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>();
                    List<SessionsView> sessionPairsList = new List<SessionsView>();
                    //logs  results from Joining Computers,Users,EventLogs tables
                    
                    foreach (var log in logs)
                    {
                        //this is login condition
                        if (log.EventTypeInt == EventLogType.Unlock)
                        {
                            sessionStart[log.ComputerId] = log.EventDateTime;
                        }
                        // this is logout conditon
                        else if ((log.EventType == EventLogType.Lock || log.EventType == EventLogType.SessionLock || log.EventType == EventLogType.SessionLogoff) &&
                            sessionStart.TryGetValue(log.ComputerId, out var startTime))
                        {
                            SessionsView sessionPair = new SessionsView
                            {
                                ComputerName = log.ComputerName,
                                LoginTime = startTime,
                                LogOutTime = log.EventDateTime,
                                Difference = (log.EventDateTime - startTime),
                                UserName = log.UserName,
                                ComputerId = log.ComputerId,
                                UserId = log.UserId
                            };
                            sessionPairsList.Add(sessionPair);
                            sessionStart.Remove(log.ComputerId);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    return sessionPairsList
        }
```

//Result projection

public class SessionsView
{

```
    public Guid ComputerId { get; set; }
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogOutTime { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Difference { get; set; }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could reduce the volume of data by grouping by `ComputerId` and `UserId` in SQL and returning just the `EventDateTime` and `EventType` columns for each group. Or you could write a stored procedure. Or you could take a look at the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186392/self-join-of-time-series-data which maybe a duplicate.